Trying to add Lua scripting support to the Zed code editor
Im trying to create a program or Zed extension that allows users to write Zed extensions in Lua instead of Rust, but can't find a way to do it. I tried using the mlua crate but embedding it into my extension struct had problems with ownership and thread safety. Here was my code:
use mlua::prelude::*;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use zed_extension_api as zed;

struct LuaExtension {
    lua: Arc<Mutex<Lua>>,
    lua_table: Arc<Mutex<LuaTable<'static>>>,
}

impl zed::Extension for LuaExtension {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        // Init Lua environment
        let lua = Lua::new();
        let lua = Arc::new(Mutex::new(lua));

        let lua_script = include_str!("test.lua");

        let lua_table = {
            let lua_lock = lua.lock().unwrap();
            let lua_table: LuaTable = lua_lock
                .load(lua_script)
                .eval()
                .expect("failed to load Lua extension");
            Arc::new(Mutex::new(lua_table))
        };

        LuaExtension { lua, lua_table }
    }

    fn language_server_command(
        &mut self,
        _language_server_id: &zed::LanguageServerId,
        _worktree: &zed::Worktree,
    ) -> Result<zed::Command, String> {
        // Call the Lua method
        let lua_table = self.lua_table.lock().unwrap();
        let result: LuaResult<Vec<String>> =
            lua_table.call_function("language_server_command", (_language_server_id, _worktree));

        match result {
            Ok(command) => Ok(zed::Command::from(command[0].clone())),
            Err(_) => Err("failed to get command from Lua".to_string()),
        }
    }

    fn run_slash_command(
        &self,
        _command: zed_extension_api::Command,
        _args: Vec<String>,
        _worktree: Option<&zed_extension_api::Worktree>,
    ) -> zed_extension_api::Result<zed_extension_api::CommandOutput, String> {
        // Call the Lua method with arguments
        let lua_table = self.lua_table.lock().unwrap();
        let result: LuaResult<String> =
            lua_table.call_function("run_slash_command", (_command, _args, _worktree));
        result.map_err(|e| e.to_string())
    }
}

zed::register_extension!(LuaExtension);

I tried wrapping the Lua instance in a Arc<Mutex<>> but that resulted in an error as the Lua class does not implement Send and Sync.

"had problems with ownership and thread safety" → What problems? Did your code fail to compile? With what error? Did your code compile but fail to run? With what error? Did your code compile and run but not do what you wanted? What did you expect and what did it do instead?

See https://docs.rs/mlua/0.9.9/mlua/#send-requirement. The code will still not compile as you are also storing a LuaTable in you struct, which will require a self-referential struct.
